# 初期ドメイン（特定ディレクトリ）から独自ドメインへリダイレクト

Tags: .htaccess

お世話になります。htaccessの書き方について教えてください。

さくらインターネットの初期ドメイン（特定ディレクトリのみ）から独自ドメインへのリダイレクトをかけたいのですが、下記書き方ですとうまくいきません。設置場所や書き方など、どなたかご教示いただけますでしょうか。先程運用始めたのですが、初期ドメインにもアクセスできて不都合を生じています。  さくらの「マルチドメインの対象のフォルダ」の指定はshoki2/で登録済みなので、独自ドメインへはアクセスできます。
どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
初期ドメイン：abcd.sakura.ne.jp/
初期ディレクトリ：abcd.sakura.ne.jp/shoki2/
```

↓

```
リダイレクト先（独自ドメイン）：example.com/
```

htaccess設置場所：shoki2/のディレクトリに下記設置してますが、いずれもうまくいきません。

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(abcd\.sakura\.ne.jp/shoki2/)(:80)?
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abcd\.sakura\.ne\.jp/shoki2/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

特定ディレクトリを含む場合の書き方が特によくわかりません。
どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

下記、ご回答ありがとうございました。転送できました。

Answer (score 1):

`http://abcd.sakura.ne.jp/shoki2/hogehoge/`

を

`http://example.com/hogehoge/`

のようにリダイレクトさせるということでしょうか？

`HTTP_HOST` にパスは入らないのでその RewriteCond だとマッチしません。

特定のディレクトリでリダイレクトさせるのであれば、その特定のディレクトリに .htaccess を配置するほうが良いです。

**shoki2/ ディレクトリの .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.sakura\.ne\.jp(:80)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

なんらかの事情で shoki2/ ディレクトリに .htaccess が配置できないのであれば RewriteRule の方にディレクトリ名を指定します。

**ドキュメントルートのの .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.sakura\.ne\.jp(:80)?$
RewriteRule ^shoki2/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```