# 特定のディレクトリのみ転送をしない設定をしたい

Tags: .htaccess

お世話になります。
特定のディレクトリのみ転送をしない設定をしたいのですが、以下htaccessの記述ではうまくいきません。
さくらインターネットでワードプレスの管理画面だけ転送かけない。ようにしたく。
どなたかご教示いただけないでしょうか。

除くディレクトリ：

```
http://abcd.sakura.ne.jp/shoki2/wp-admin/
```

以下2行目の書き方ではうまくいきませんでした。

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.sakura\.ne\.jp(:80)?$
RewriteCond %{http://abcd.sakura.ne.jp/} !(^/shoki2/wp-admin/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

因みに、さくらインターネットで「初期ドメインから独自ドメインの転送の仕方」を[他の質問スレッド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8083/%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3-%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E7%8B%AC%E8%87%AA%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%B8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88)でしていましたが、追加質問の為新規にスレッドを立てました。
どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

下記、回答ありがとうございます。htaccessは/shoki2/に置いてうまくいかなかったので、/shoki2/wp-admin/にも置いてみましたがうまくいきませんでした。一旦ルールを終わらせてから書くとは具体的にどのように書いたらよいでしょうか。ご教示いただけますでしょうか。

```
RewriteRule ^/shoki2/wp-admin/ - [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.sakura\.ne\.jp(:80)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/shoki2/wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

で良いでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

もう解決しているかもしれませんが、恒久的に新規ドメイン(独自ドメイン)への転送を行いつつ、特定のディレクトリだけ「転送しない」ということであれば、簡単ですが下記のようなルールを書いた`.htaccess`をドキュメントルート(/)に配置してみてはいかがでしょうか。
(@suzukisさんのとほぼ同じですが…)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/shoki2/wp-admin/)
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

また、一旦ルールを終わらせてから書く、というのは RewriteRule の末尾に付与するオプション **[ ]** で **L** を指定してあげることだと思います。
このオプション **[L]** は、条件にマッチした場合そこで判定を終了するという意味を持ちます(つまりこの後に続く RewriteRule を評価しません)

ですので、このオプションを一連のルールの頭に持ってくることで、ルールにマッチした URL は転送処理まで辿り着かずに終了し、指定の URL アクセスを転送設定から除外することができます。

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/shoki2/wp-admin/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/shoki2/test1/ http://example.co.jp/test1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/shoki2/test2/ http://example.co.jp/test2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/shoki2/test3/ http://example.ne.jp/test3/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/shoki2/test4/ http://example.ne.jp/test4/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

最初の方で

```
RewriteRule ^/shoki2/wp-admin/ - [L]
```

でルールを終わらせてから、転送のルールを設定するといいのではないでしょうか。